# register woocommerce by phone number instead email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration

i'm trying to simplify user registration in woo-commerce for my customers.
i my customers usually don't know about email! and they don't need to that at all!

so i want to remove email filed from both woo-commerce registration form and checkout form.
so may be this is good way that i paste phone number automatically in email filed and add @  and  .com    to fill this field.
also paste phone number in username automatically.

can any body help me how to do this?!
thank a lot.

Comment: Everything in woocommerce is based on user email. for example when they loose their password, the email notifications… So you can't do that simply. It's a huge development to make that work. you need to replace that by an SMS feature like… This question is just too broad as you don't provide any code and additionally *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"*

Comment: very thanks .   in my idea i want we need to a mobile number just for sending forgot password via sms.

Comment: use "digits plugin" as the best solution for OTP and SMS structure for your wordpress website.